# Arch Linux gateway - can't ping internet interface

Tags: linux, routing, ip, gateway, forwarding

I've set up a simple gateway with Arch Linux:

```
GATEWAY# ifconfig eth0 172.27.210.221 netmask 255.255.255.0
GATEWAY# ifconfig wlan0 10.8.221.221 netmask 255.255.0.0
GATEWAY# iwconfig wlan0 essid OpenWifi
GATEWAY# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

This is the actual routing table on the gateway:

```
DESTINATION     GATEWAY GENMASK         FLAGS   METRIC  REF USE IFACE
10.8.0.0        0.0.0.0 255.255.0.0     U       0       0   0   wlan0
172.27.210.0    0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0   U       202     0   0   eth0
```

I disabled rp_filter on all interfaces.

The eth0 is connected to a switch I don't have access to. The interface will be configured to access the Internet when everything works. The wlan0 is connected to an open network infrastructure.

I have a client PC, Arch Linux based, connected to the same wireless network with the following setup:

```
CLIENT# iwconfig wlan0 essid OpenWifi
CLIENT# ifconfig wlan0 10.8.221.222 netmask 255.255.0.0
CLIENT# route add default gw 10.8.221.221 wlan0
```

Now, I know that to share the Internet connection, I need add a default route and set up NAT on the gateway machine. But I suppose I should be able to ping the eth0 interface of the gateway from my client, without any additional configuration:

```
CLIENT# ping 172.27.210.221
```

The thing is, I don't get any reply.

A tcpdump on the gateway wlan0 interface, shows the ICMP requests coming in and the replies from 172.27.210.221 to 10.8.221.222 but actually I don't receive anything back on the client (I confirmed this with a tcpdump on the client).

If I replicate this setup on two VMs, using only ethernet interfaces, I have no problems at all. Do you have any idea what could be the problem? Could it be related to the wireless network?

**UPDATE 1**

The following is the output of a iwconfig wlan0, iptables -nvL and a tcpdump -npe on client and gateway during a ping from the client 10.8.221.222 to the gateway 172.27.210.221:

Gateway:

```
iwconfig wlp2s0b1
wlp2s0b1  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"OpenWifi"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: xxxxxxxxxxxx   
      Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=11 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-29 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:79  Invalid misc:772   Missed beacon:0


iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 172K packets, 22M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1132 packets, 95328 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination    


tcpdump -npe 'icmp'
03:29:23.876193 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 1, length 64
03:29:23.876277 yyyyyyyyyyyyyy > xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.27.210.221 > 10.8.221.222: ICMP echo reply, id 13006, seq 1, length 64
03:29:24.893768 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 2, length 64
03:29:24.893842 yyyyyyyyyyyyyy > xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.27.210.221 > 10.8.221.222: ICMP echo reply, id 13006, seq 2, length 64
03:29:25.908918 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 3, length 64
03:29:25.908999 yyyyyyyyyyyyyy > xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.27.210.221 > 10.8.221.222: ICMP echo reply, id 13006, seq 3, length 64
03:29:26.920903 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 4, length 64
03:29:26.920969 yyyyyyyyyyyyyy > xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.27.210.221 > 10.8.221.222: ICMP echo reply, id 13006, seq 4, length 64
03:29:27.933499 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 5, length 64
03:29:27.933618 yyyyyyyyyyyyyy > xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.27.210.221 > 10.8.221.222: ICMP echo reply, id 13006, seq 5, length 64
03:29:28.944583 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 6, length 64
03:29:28.944650 yyyyyyyyyyyyyy > xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.27.210.221 > 10.8.221.222: ICMP echo reply, id 13006, seq 6, length 64
03:29:29.958243 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 7, length 64
03:29:29.958323 yyyyyyyyyyyyyy > xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.27.210.221 > 10.8.221.222: ICMP echo reply, id 13006, seq 7, length 64
03:29:30.971649 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 8, length 64
03:29:30.971744 yyyyyyyyyyyyyy > xxxxxxxxxxxxxx, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 172.27.210.221 > 10.8.221.222: ICMP echo reply, id 13006, seq 8, length 64
```

Client:

```
iwconfig wlp1s0
wlp1s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"OpenWifi"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: xxxxxxxxxxxx   
      Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=11 dBm   
      Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Encryption key:off
      Power Management:on
      Link Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:26   Missed beacon:0


iptables -nvL
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 1665 packets, 149K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 765 packets, 64260 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination     


tcpdump -npe 'icmp'
12:29:30.950270 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 1, length 64
12:29:31.968238 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 2, length 64
12:29:32.981538 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 3, length 64
12:29:33.994868 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 4, length 64
12:29:35.008223 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 5, length 64
12:29:36.021575 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 6, length 64
12:29:37.034884 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 7, length 64
12:29:38.048205 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 8, length 64
12:29:39.061533 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 9, length 64
12:29:40.074884 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 10, length 64
12:29:41.088206 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 11, length 64
12:29:42.101534 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 12, length 64
12:29:43.114876 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 13, length 64
12:29:44.128193 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 14, length 64
12:29:45.141535 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 15, length 64
12:29:46.154870 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 16, length 64
12:29:47.168208 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 17, length 64
12:29:48.181573 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 18, length 64
12:29:49.194868 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 19, length 64
12:29:50.208171 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 20, length 64
12:29:51.221531 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 21, length 64
12:29:52.234870 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 22, length 64
12:29:53.248185 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 23, length 64
12:29:54.261521 xxxxxxxxxxxxxx > yyyyyyyyyyyyyy, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 98: 10.8.221.222 > 172.27.210.221: ICMP echo request, id 13006, seq 24, length 64
```

Comment: How did you setup NAT?

Comment: Hi Ipor: the packets are not leaving the gateway at this point of my setup, so I didn't configure it yet.

Answer (score 0):

What you described should work.
Try to disable iptables and try your ping again.

Comment: I didn't mess with iptables at all. Everything is on ACCEPT.

Comment: Can you post: a iwconfig wlan0, a tcpdump -e in the client while pinging client -> server and iptables -nvL of both client and server?

Comment: Hi Fredi: added the info you asked for in the first post.